# pearson correlation using np.random.rand failing

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code to calculate the correlation coefficient using two different ways to generate number series. It fails to work for the first way (corr_coeff_pearson) but works for the 2nd way (corr_coeff_pearson_1). Why is this so? In both cases, the variables are of class 'numpy.ndarray'

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1000)

inp_vct_lngt = 5

X = 2*np.random.rand(inp_vct_lngt,1)
y=4+3*X+np.random.randn(inp_vct_lngt,1)
print(type(X))

corr_coeff_pearson=0
corr_coeff_pearson = np.corrcoef(X,y)
print("Pearson Correlation:")
print(corr_coeff_pearson)

X_1 = np.random.randint(0,50,5)
y_1 = X_1 + np.random.normal(0,10,5)
print(type(X_1))

corr_coeff_pearson_1 = np.corrcoef(X_1,y_1)
print("Pearson Correlation:")
print(corr_coeff_pearson_1)
```

Is there some way to "convert" the number in the first way of generating the series that I am missing?

Comment: what is not working? is it throwing an error? and why do you initialize `corrcoeff_pearson` with `0` whereas you are not doing it with the other coeff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `X` and `y` are 2 dimensional:

```
>>> X
array([[1.9330627 ],
       [0.19204405],
       [0.21168505],
       [0.65018234],
       [0.83079548]])
>>> y
array([[8.60619212],
       [6.09210226],
       [5.33097283],
       [5.71649684],
       [5.18771916]])
```

So `corrcoef` is thinking

> Each row of x represents a variable, and each column a single observation of all those variables

(quoted from the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html))

What you can do is either flatten the two to one dimension:

```
>>> np.corrcoef(X.flatten(),y.flatten())
array([[1.        , 0.84196446],
       [0.84196446, 1.        ]])
```

Or use `rowvar=False`:

```
>>> np.corrcoef(X,y,rowvar=False)
array([[1.        , 0.84196446],
       [0.84196446, 1.        ]])
```

Comment: perfect! that is what I thought too, but I had no idea how to flatten it. Any thoughts on when we should use .flatten() vs rowvar=False?

Comment: I think `rowvar=False` is more appropriate, but that's just because it sort of forces the user to think about what it is they are achieving...